# Understanding client_id and client_secret

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, owin

A bit of a beginner to OAUTH and wanted to ask if I understood something correctly. I'm using OWIN and C# and I setup the following scenario:

1. a user makes a request to my token endpoint, passing in a username/password with a grant_type of password. If the credentials are valid, then I create a JWT.
2. The user gets back a JWT, and then the client uses that token going forward for all requests
3. Any requests that require authorization I use the token's claims to ensure the user is allowed to make this request.

So where does the client_id and client_secret come into this? Is this just an extra layer of security to say "before you can even get a token, you need to pass me *another* set of credentials (id/secret) and only if *those* are valid, in addition to your username/password provided, can you get back a JWT?

Would like to understand who the two relate - Thanks so much!

Comment: Those are used on validation of the token to make sure both sides match. Kind of like when you use a google maps api key. One is created on their side for you when you register and you get the same key that you will pass in on each request.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both client_id and client_secret are not used in the password flow. However, as you are probably aware, OAuth2 has other flows, suited for other scenarios.

Namely:

- the **authorization code** flow used in web apps that authenticate users server side. The client_id is used in the initial redirect, the client_secret is used in the last step where the app exchanges the one time code for a token.
- the **client credentials** flow used to authenticate applications rather than individual users

A concise reference of all various flows: https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified

Comment: So when I'm just aiming to let a user log in to the system, it sounds like I wouldn't need a client_id or client_secret? Or if so, why can't I just let the user login w/ a username/password to get back a token, and i'm done?

Comment: @user3379785: why? Because to learn username/password, your app has to ask for both. And no one is going to risk providing their google/facebook credentials by providing them in an unknown page. The authorization code flow **redirects** the browser to the provider page so that credentials are provided on their page, leaving no room for unwanted leak.

Comment: My front end is on the same domain as my backend API. And only my app is the one making the calls to get a JWT with the user's username/password. So in my case, no need for a client_id or secret? I actually wouldn't see how a secret gets used since it's direct JS calls to my API, and my backend API is handling the checking of credentials and issuing of JWT

Comment: Sounds like you don't need client_id/client_secret then.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It seems like client_id/client_secret is best in a case where someone on a server calls to you and you want to verify them before you give them a JWT?

Comment: You say, "The client_id is used in the initial redirect, the client_secret is used in the last step where the app exchanges the one time code for a token" -- but I can find nowhere in the offical OAuth2 spec for the [Authorization Code Grant](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1) indicating the client secret can (or should) be used in the subsequent access token request. What leads you to believe it should be used here?

Comment: It is step D in the diagram you linked. The specs says it clearly "When making the request, the client authenticates with the authorization server.".

Answer (score 7):

There are two parties that need to be authenticated: the application and the user.

The application is authenticated with the ID and secret, possibly backed up by the callback URL, which should ensure that the recipient of the token is the right one.

The user is authenticated through the OAuth provider. It can use a username/password for it, or whatever the OAuth provider deems necessary. That token is used to allow the application to get the user data without knowing the username and password.

Comment: So this is just to prevent unauthorized applications from making calls to my API? Even if the call is to an anonymous action in my API, I can restrict the usage so only the client can access it? ok thanks. So generally you always want to pass the API key/secret, as well as the token, in each request?

Comment: Yes, it is a basic authentication mechanism.

Comment: I don't understand how the ID and secret work... if we're talking about an app, those spend some time unencrypted on the device. Those would be fairly trivial for a hacker to pull and use in their own app, no?

Comment: Then they should not reside on the device. @ArtOfWarfare

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Then where would they reside? How is the application getting authenticated?

Comment: There are other flows that do not require the client secret. Those are safe to use on an untrusted device. (The client ID is public information, so it is no problem to store that on the device).